# How to trigger SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2?

Tags: c, signals

I'm getting acquainted with signals in C. I can't figure out what kind of signals `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` are and how can I trigger them. Can anyone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

They are *user-defined* signals, so they aren't triggered by any particular action.  You can explicitly send them programmatically:

```
#include <signal.h>

kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
```

where `pid` is the process id of the receiving process.  At the receiving end, you can register a signal handler for them:

```
#include <signal.h>

void my_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
    }
}

signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If these signals are user-defined how can they be useful? Can you give me some examples?

Comment: @haunted: They are designed for simple inter-process communication (IPC).  So a child process could send it to its parent to indicate that it's completed a certain task, for instance.  Obviously, much more sophisticated techniques exist for IPC (such as pipes, sockets, semaphores, etc.).

Comment: I would avoid using them for any program-internal IPC, but the one place they can be useful is as a cheap form of user-to-program input via the kill command.

Comment: @haunted85: a concrete example would be mongodb rotating it's log files when receiving SIGUSR1: - see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/

Comment: @haunted85 Here is an example using `SIGUSR1` for AIO: http://linux.die.net/man/7/aio

Comment: QEMU uses this technique a lot to kick start a cpu model.

Answer (score 8):

terminal 1

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=debian.img
```

terminal 2

```
killall -SIGUSR1 dd
```

go back to terminal 1

```
34292201+0 records in
34292200+0 records out
17557606400 bytes (18 GB) copied, 1034.7 s, 17.0 MB/s
```

Comment: this does not work with rsync btw: `rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(1434) [sender=3.1.1]`

Comment: Of course it doesn't have to work with `rsync`, it was just an example of an application (here: `dd`) that sets up a signal handler for SIGUSR1 for a useful function.

Answer (score 7):

They are signals that application developers use. The kernel shouldn't ever send these to a process. You can send them using `kill(2)` or using the utility `kill(1)`.

If you intend to use signals for synchronization you might want to check real-time signals (there's more of them, they are queued, their delivery order is guaranteed etc).