# How can I display the output for sigusr1 and sigusr2?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals

I am a beginner in C and system programming.  I wrote a program and it should display the following: 
Caught SIGUSR1
Caught SIGUSR2
Caught SIGINT

However, when I do "./test.c", the only thing I see is "Caught SIGINT" when I type Ctrl-C.  How can I fix my code so my program displays the messages above?  Sorry if my question is dumb. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

EDITED:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sigHandler_sigusr1(int sig)
{
    //sig contains the signal number that was received
    printf("Caught SIGUSR1, %d\n", getpid());
    //kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
}

static void sigHandler_sigusr2(int sig)
{
    //sig contains the signal number that was received
    printf("Caught SIGSR2, %d\n", getpid());
    //kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);
}

static void sigHandler_sigint(int sig)
{
    //sig contains the signal number that was received
    printf("Caught SIGINT, Existing, %d\n", getpid());
    //kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler_sigusr1) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Unable to create handler for SIGUSR1\n");

    if (signal(SIGUSR2, sigHandler_sigusr2) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Unable to create handler for SIGUSR2\n");

    if (signal(SIGINT, sigHandler_sigint) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Unable to create handler for SIGINT\n");

    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);
    kill(getpid(), SIGINT);

    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my suggestion is  [avoid using printf in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891065#16891065)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all looks good.

With SIGUSR's you have to explicitly call them in the program. You can't trigger them with ctrl-z or ctrl-c.

You didn't show any code where you try and trigger the signals.

Comment: How can I trigger the signals in my code? Should I put kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1) in my main method?

Comment: Yes, kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1), and kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2)

Comment: Hi. I just try that. It doesn't work. I posted my new code here. Do you mind to take a look and let me know what I'm missing? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

In order to active the signal handler function you need to send signal to the procces.
It is missing from your code.

This is how you send signal to yourself:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
```

You need to do it for `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`.

The reason you can see `SIGINT` message is that when you press `ctrl+c` you actually sending a `SIGINT` singal to your procces.

Comment: Hi. Does that mean I should put kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1) in my main method?

Comment: Yes. Also `kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);` in order to active both. And if you want to make `SIGINT` without pressing `crtl+c` you should do `kill(getpid(), SIGINT);`

Comment: Hi. I just try that. It doesn't work. I'll post my new code here. Do you mind to take a look and let me know what I'm missing? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong, but `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` are user specified signals.

When you do "Ctrl-C", you do an interrupt, caught by `SIGINT` handler.

In order to caught `SIGUSR1` ans `SIGUSR2` you have to throw them yourself :

```
kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
```

[More informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168636/how-to-trigger-sigusr1-and-sigusr2)

Comment: Hi. Does that mean I should put kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1) in my main method?