# How to bind a custom signal key in bash？

Tags: bash, signals, readline

As we all know, pressing Control-c in bash can send SIGINT to the foreground program, but I want to know is there a way to configure bash or readline(inputrc) to send SIGUSR1 to the foreground program when I press Control-s ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168636/how-to-trigger-sigusr1-and-sigusr2

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/288772/shell-sigkill-keybinding/417991#417991